# How do I add values to partition function and scheme?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

We have a partition function defined as

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [PartitionByPeriodFunction](int) 
AS RANGE LEFT 
FOR VALUES (20101228, ... , 20161227)
```

where each date is the first date of our fiscal period.

We have a partition scheme defined as

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [PartitionByPeriodScheme] 
AS PARTITION [PartitionByPeriodFunction] 
TO ([FactsBefore2011], ..., [FactsP201612], [FactsAfter2016])
```

I want to add more periods to the partition function and more filegroups to the partition scheme - what is the best way to do this?

I have read to drop and recreate the function and scheme - will the dependent objects allow that? I am unsure how to use split since I am not wanting to split 20161227 but rather continue the pattern.

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the partition scheme and function to effectively add a new partition.

```
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME [PartitionByPeriodScheme] NEXT USED [FactsAfter2016_2];
```

Follow this up with:

```
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION [PartitionByPeriodFunction]() SPLIT RANGE 20171231;
```

This will add a range between 20161227 and 20171231, which will be placed on  `[FactsAfter2016_2]`.

As always, try this on a non-production system first.

Comment: Since the partition function was created with `RANGE LEFT`, would the split have to apply to the left-hand side (a value earlier than 20101228)?

Comment: No.  LEFT or RIGHT is about where the boundaries sit.